# where :thisyear > :last unless :last nil?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an sql search query in my rails app:

```
 patients = patients.where("thisyear < last ") if search.present?
```

My problem is that this search query also disselects database entrys where the `:last` is nil

My question is how can i write an search query that does not get applied on patients where the column `:last` is `nil`? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`patients = patients.where("last IS NULL OR thisyear < last") if search.present?`